# ssh fails: image not found [preauth]

Tags: macos, ssh, homebrew

When I try to SSH to my computer, ssh fails with this error:

```
Mothership:~ kuyan$ ssh kuyan@localhost
Connection closed by ::1
```

This also happens when I attempt to SSH to my user from another computer.
This message appears in Console when I attempt to connect:

```
12/12/12 3:44:30.468 PM sshd[2576]: fatal: ssh_sandbox_child: sandbox_init: dlopen(/usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib, 261): image not found [preauth]
```

Relevant information:

- I'm using a different version of sshd than OS X provides, installed via `brew install openssh` - but this error occurs with both versions.
- `/usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib` exists:

  ```
  Mothership:~ kuyan$ ls /usr/lib/libsandbox*
  /usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib /usr/lib/libsandbox.dylib
  ```
- Here's my [/etc/sshd_config](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rCgwN9kA). The relevant line seems to be `UsePrivilegeSeparation`: when uncommented and set to `yes` instead of `sandbox`, everything works A-OK.
- Though I'm not using MacPorts, the error I'm getting is essentially the one [here](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/36291).
- sshd version: `OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011`

Comment: When you configure OpenSSH before the build, you should include `--with-libs="-lsandbox"`. The Macports and Homebrew folks should probably do the same. From building OpenSSH from scratch (see [Building OpenSSH for OS X?](http://superuser.com/q/961349/173513)), I know its not included on OS X but its needed to avoid ***`fatal: ssh_sandbox_child: sandbox_init: dlopen(/usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib, 261): image not found [preauth]`***. I also think its the easiest way to avoid it rather than hacking the source code.

Answer (score 3):

dtruss shows:

```
2892/0xdc8e:  stat64("/usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib\0", 0x7FFF500DA5F0, 0x7FFF500DB500)        = -1 Err#2
```

which is ENOENT (No such file or directory) and the reason is probably that chroot already happened.  If you are so foolish as to experiment by

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/empty/usr/lib
sudo cp /usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib /var/empty/usr/lib
```

You will move the crash to the next shlib not under /var/empty/

```
sshd[3256]: fatal: ssh_sandbox_child: sandbox_init: dlopen (/usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib, 261):
Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib\\n  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib\\n  Reason: image not found [preauth]
```

If you persist with this madness

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib /usr/lib/libMatch.1.dylib /var/empty/usr/lib/
```

sshd will start to work again at least for SSH keys, passwords still don't work.

You can also edit `/usr/local/etc/sshd_config` changing

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
```

into

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
```

But outside of debugging purposes I don't suggest trying any of this.

Comment: Can you say more about why 'UsePrivilegeSeparation yes' is insufficient? Because right now that's the only option (AFAICT) if you want to use a non-standard sshd.

Comment: "This madness" is stock behavior from an OpenSSH download. I don't think the guy asking the question is doing anything special, other than using and building OpenSSH as intended by the OpenSSH team.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this problem in MacPorts' sshd by porting a patch from Apple's sshd (which can be found at http://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-186/). Apple moved the function that calls `sandbox_init(3)` (which calls `dlopen(3)` internally) before the `chroot(2)` call that would make loading the library fail.

The required patches are

- http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/net/openssh/files/patch-sandbox-darwin.c-apple-sandbox-named-external.diff,
- http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/net/openssh/files/patch-sshd.c-apple-sandbox-named-external.diff and
- putting http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/net/openssh/files/org.openssh.sshd.sb into the location referenced in the first patch.

and openssh needs to be built with `-D__APPLE_SANDBOX_NAMED_EXTERNAL__` in the preprocessor flags.

The failure to authenticate with passwords is because OS X doesn't support the required library functions to do that without using PAM. Setting `UsePAM yes` in your `sshd_config` should work (as should applying http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/net/openssh/files/pam.patch, which changes the default to enabling PAM).

Comment: Why not configure with `--with-libs="-lsandbox"`? Its much easier than patching the source code. The dependency will ensure `libsandbox` is loaded by [`dyld(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) at load time. There will be no need to mess with dynamic loading at the wrong time.

Comment: I just used the patches that Apple applies to the copy of OpenSSH they ship with OS X. They allow the use of a (possibly more specific, I couldn't quickly find the actual definition of `kSBXProfilePureComputation`) named sandbox, which needs to be loaded at runtime and requires moving the sandboxing before the chroot. So this is really more about (a) supporting a named sandbox rather than supporting sandboxing in general, which could be done with `-lsandbox`, and (b) aligning with the behavior of Apple's OpenSSH.