# Setting up "HPN-SSH - High Performance SSH/SCP" on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ssh, homebrew

As you'd expect from the name, 
[HPN-SSH - High Performance SSH/SCP](http://www.psc.edu/index.php/hpn-ssh)
is a "high performance" patch of SSH/SCP.

I've installed a newer version of OpenSSL via Homebrew 
(`brew install openssl`).

I've downloaded the source code (openssh-6.1p1.tar.gz) and applied the patch (openssh-6.1p1-hpn13v14.diff.gz), compiled it, and installed it to /usr/local/.

However, the default version of ssh/sshd seems to be hard-coded into the OS enough that I can't get the new version to work after editing `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist` and `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`.

I was getting this error:

> ssh_sandbox_child: sandbox_init: dlopen(/usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib, 261): image not found [preauth]

I found an answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74715/ssh-fails-image-not-found-preauth) which suggested editing `/usr/local/etc/sshd_config` to change  `UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox` to `UsePrivilegeSeparation yes` but that is apparently not recommended (for reasons I do not entirely understand).

At this point I do not know what to do next.

1. Can someone explain why `UsePrivilegeSeparation yes` is such a bad idea?
2. Is there a way for me to run HPN-SSH and regular SSH at the same time? (I was thinking of setting the new `sshd` on a different port than the regular `sshd` but I'm not sure if that is a good idea or if there is something else I should be doing.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at #1.

It looks like the sandbox prevents the application from producing new threads.  From what I found online, the sandbox functionality was only recently introduced in OpenSSH 5.8 so if someone finds a bug in OpenSSH that is limited only by the sandbox, they could exploit this attack vector.

The question is, do you have a team of government spooks decided that this would be the easiest attack vector and would willing to dedicate resources to find an obscure bug in OpenSSH which would only be limited by this *particular* sandbox?

As for #2 ... I can't think of any reason why that wouldn't work.

Oh, and I just figured out that MacPorts has the hpn version: `sudo port install openssh +hpn`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a homebrew tap that [has it](https://github.com/rdp/homebrew-openssh-gssapi) (mine LOL)

```
brew tap rdp/homebrew-openssh-gssapi
brew install rdp/homebrew-openssh-gssapi/openssh-patched --with-hpn
```

then it'll be the default on the PATH at least, not sure on getting `sshd` to use it...