# Switch to MacPorts SSH by default 10.8/10.9

Tags: ssh, macports

I've installed the MacPorts [high-performance](http://www.psc.edu/index.php/hpn-ssh) variant of SSH (`sudo port install openssh +hpn`) but now I would like to switch the default ssh command over.  However, there appears to be some [moral panic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74715/ssh-fails-image-not-found-preauth) around degrading the sandbox (which was only recently introduced) but I am also worried about integration with OS X's keychain and my server keys....

What all do I need to softlink into /usr/bin/ssh or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list the /opt directories before the system path and the shell will prefer the first match for `ssh` unless a script explicitly calls the system version.

By default, MacPorts lists /opt/ in your $PATH before the standard system paths.  I would inspect your `~/.bash_profile` carefully to make sure there are no typos.